# When I try and run pyspark.cmd I get the error message "find: 'version': No such file or directory"

Tags: python, apache-spark, anaconda

I'm trying to get started with Apache Spark. I'd like to use it via python. However, when I run pyspark from the command line I get the following error message:

```
C:\Programs\Apache\Spark\spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4\bin>pyspark.cmd
Running python with PYTHONPATH=C:\Programs\Apache\Spark\spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.
4\bin\..\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip;C:\Programs\Apache\Spark\spark-1.2.0-bi
n-hadoop2.4\bin\..\python;
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (32-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:13:35) [MSC v.1
500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
find: 'version': No such file or directory
else was unexpected at this time.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\Apache\Spark\spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4\bin\..\python\pyspark
\shell.py", line 45, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PySparkShell", pyFiles=add_files)
  File "C:\Programs\Apache\Spark\spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4\python\pyspark\contex
t.py", line 102, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway)
  File "C:\Programs\Apache\Spark\spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4\python\pyspark\contex
t.py", line 211, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway()
  File "C:\Programs\Apache\Spark\spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4\python\pyspark\java_g
ateway.py", line 73, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception(error_msg)
Exception: Launching GatewayServer failed with exit code 255!
Warning: Expected GatewayServer to output a port, but found no output.
```

When I try and run the scala interface by running spark-shell I get the message:

```
find: 'version': No such file or directory
else was unexpected at this time.
```

I cant find any info on this error online, other than

which turned out to be a dead end. 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3808
Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem in spark 1.2.0 but not in spark 1.0.2.
The reason was in my case that I had cygwin in the DOS classpath.
Spark uses the find command in the file 'spark-class2.cmd', which used then the cygwin find command instead of the DOS find command, which works somewhat different.
I removed cygwin from the DOS PATH, which solved the problem.

Regards, Felix

Comment: Thanks - I had another program on the PATH which had its own find command, but this is correct.